# Azure API Management with OAuth2.0 and AAD login causes repeated loop

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-authentication, microsoft-identity-web

We have a simple web application and I am trying to use Azure API Management on top of it. Right now, I am redirecting the CName of our web application product to the apim url.

Our web application is a first party application and it performs AAD auth from `Microsoft.Identity.Web` nuget package and gets the access_token as below:

```
string accessToken = tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { Configuration["Scopes:<product>"] }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Right now, I am redirecting all the traffic (GET /* and POST /*) from the CName to the apim url

Without the APIM usage, our Network Calls (Successful) looks like this:
[Without APIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhGHx.png)

However, on adding the APIM layer, our Network Calls looks like this:
[With APIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEheC.png)

Somehow the `/signin-oidc` request redirects the call to `login.microsoftonline.com/..` instead of authorizing the request and redirecting back to the root (path: `'/'`) of the caller page.

We get repeated loop:

```
apim-url => login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/.. => login.live.com/... => apim-url/signin-oidc =>  login.microsoftonline.com/consumers => ...
```

I am not sure if the redirect isn't working correctly or if the auth is not working.

Any leads would be helpful,

Thanks,

Manisha

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you got that behavior but, often authentification loop come from bad redirectUrl.

You are using a dns redirect, so you should add to AAD the 2 Redirect Url in the portal :

apim-url/signin-oidc and [yourdomain]/signin-oidc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we already have that, without that we got the error "Incorrect redirect uri"

Comment: Sorry for that, did you use a CDN or some kind of Proxy ?

Comment: Nope, we aren't using any kind of Proxy, just simply letting apim to redirect to our hosted url.

Comment: Last thing i could think about is a secret key error or a bad configuration in AAD for the app...

Comment: Did your architechture look like this one ? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/enterprise-integration/basic-enterprise-integration

Comment: Not really, here, in my architecture, the user hits the apim url, the apim forwards the traffic to my web application, my web app does the Auth via AAD which returns back the Auth header to my web app which gets redirected back to the calling host (in this case is my apim url)

Comment: I think it's a bad AAD authorization Relay pb. If it's your app that does the AAD check (and not the apim) then you should have some config mistake somewhere. Apim act as a gateway, so i suppose that it is like an Authorization breaker (less security after the gateway for reduce the chatiness of the services calls). If i understands well, you send the authorization header from the client, apim try to relay this header to your service and your service try to authenticate the request with that ? I think there is something wrong in this process.

Comment: I always seem Apim like a "Managable Gateway Service" (with workflow and orchestration) , not like a simple proxy like.  - Did you try to use your architecture (for test) with out the authentification ? did this work ?

Comment: Yeah, somehow it feels like the AAD Auth problem, I just don't know if it fixable though. I tested Api (with inherited Auth header) and they work fine, just when they don't have this Auth header, it is a problem  :( Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

I just try it from scratch :

- Create a azure api managment service
- Add a Gateway -let call it "my-gateway"
- Add an Api (I choose a Azure function with AAD authentification on it) let call it "my-api"
- In the Settings of the API (API => my-api => Settings) I remove Subscription requested (only for the test) and I check None for User Authorization (because it's my function who is in charge for that in my test, not the gateway)

Now I test in my Http Client (for me it's Advance REST Client) to call the gateway :

https://my-gateway.azure-api.net/my-api

In the header i add : Authorization : Bearer [xxxx - Security Token]

If all the AAD configuration are ok , it would work fine (it works for me)

If not, your pb is in the AAD configuration of the your api (or in some bad implementation of the AuthO/OpenId inside your API code)

If possible, share with us some of your code for the Security part in your API.

Comment: If none of that worked, Try to use a policy between gateway and your api : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/use-oauth2-for-authorization